# UIPickerView Separator lines

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am using Xcode 7.1.1 in my application I am using `UIPickerView` for selecting countries. It's working fine, I need two separator lines.

I tried to use this code:

```
[myPicker.subviews objectAtIndex:1].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[myPicker.subviews objectAtIndex:2].backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

but it showing line only in the bottom, in the top there is no line. Is there any way to show two lines between the bold text?

[image]

Comment: What is the type of objects in your UIPickerView?NSString or UILabel?? check by NSLogging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the myPicker.subviews you are trying to access is not something you know about. It does not contain what you think, that is, view or anything. Its apple private api and it can be anything. You cannot depend on it. It also depends on OS.

To make the selected text some sort of distinctly visible what you alternatively do is for all model objects create a corresponding UILabel in a loop and then use them to supply the data to the picker. Then in the

```
pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

set some distinct property of your UILabel like change its textcolor or font.

Comment: Check what does NSLog of [myPicker.subviews objectAtIndex:1] give?

Comment: Yes checking your suggestions

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works  -(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    id obj = [self.data objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) row];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, pickerView.frame.size.height-10)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Museo Sans" size:20];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@", obj];
    return label;
}

Answer (score 1):

add 1 pixel view in xib

hide both view & picker.

when you show picker..then display picker & 1 pixel view

when you click on cancel or Done remove your picker &  1 pixel view